# Real linguists, please feel free to boldly improve our tagging

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms, tags, retagging

Sometimes us armchair linguists and language enthusiasts don't know the all the right terms or some subtle difference between terms or that two terms are actually synonyms.

I've been pretty hazy on how to tag some of my recent questions so please improve my tagging by correcting any poorly chosen tags that could be better linguistic terms. Keep in mind also that when two terms are equal for a topic we can also create tag synonyms.

Comment: Do you know how we go about creating tag synonyms?  It seems that 1250 reputation is needed to do that, which no one has yet(?).  Can a moderator do it in the meantime, or do we need to wait until that reputation threshold is crossed in order to have synonyms?

Comment: @Aaron: During the beta the best way is to ask a question about each proposed synonym on meta and a SE person can do it or soon I suppose we'll get some pro-tem moderators appointed and they'll be able to do it too. Also you will need enough "points" in the tag to suggest synonyms so a way to achieve that might be to use both synonyms for now and they'll get synonymized later. Within reason of course since there's only five tags per question and you might need them all.

Comment: So, what are the tags for? Are they metadata for searching? If so, I can't find where we can search by tags.

Comment: Also, there aren't tags for much linguistic terminology--should we have tags for 'phonology', 'phonetics', etc?

Comment: You can search and filter by tags. I never use them for searching but I do use the filtering, especially on the busier SE sites. You can select tags you are interested in and ones you are not interested in. These will highlight or dim questions in and out of your interest in the big lists. You can also click on a tag and will only see questions thus tagged. I'm sure you can do more too, this is just what I've found easily by experimentation.

Answer (score 1):

Since you ask about tagging, I want to include a simple guide:

1. Search tags using the search bar.

   Just type the name of the tag, and you'll find all of the questions that have that tag:

   > [phonology]
2. This can also be done with **multiple tags**:

   > [phonology] [intonation]
3. Search for some tags but exclude others:

   For example, I want to search questions with the [phonology](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phonology) tag, but exclude the ones with the [intonation](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/intonation) tag. So I'll write:

   > [phonology] -[intonation]